# Is Gravitational Constant $G$ really a Constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, physical-constants

Let us assume that this was the case that newton thought

consider The following case

Two Bodies Of mass 'M1' and mass 'M2' are positioned at a separation of distance 'r'

F is proportional to M1
: .F = K₁M₁....(1)

F is proportional to M2
: F = K₂M₂......(2)

F is proportional to 1/r²
:F = K₃/r² ......(3)

So by multiplying (1),(2),(3)

F³=K₁K₂K₃M₁M₂/r²

But K₁ = F/M₁

And
K₂ = F/M₂

And
K₃ = Fr²

Hence
F³=(F³r²/M₁M₂)×M₁M₂/r²

Hence F=(Fr²/M₁M₂)M₁M₂/r²

Then Sir Newton stated that this

Fr²/M₁M₂ is a constant,say G

Hence F=GM₁M₂/r²

How did they stated that G is a constant
As the G=Fr²/M₁M₂

G is dependant on F,r² and M₁M₂

But this contradicts the statement that G is Universal gravitational constant that does not depend on anything?

How can be this possible?

Comment: Please consider writing the question in LaTex

Comment: @LoneAcademic,Is it better now?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/635100/2451

Comment: Note that [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is the site standard for writing equations on Physics SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem faced by people just beginning to study physics. Newton formulated that the force of gravity between two objects varies as product of their masses and inversely proportional to square of the distance between them. Therefore

$$F \propto \dfrac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

Now, these two needed to be connected by a proportionality constant, which came out to be known as $G$ and with a value $6.67 \times 10^{-11}\ \text{Newton}\ kg^{-2}\ m^{-2}$.

About the question you have asked above- It does not matter what objects you take and what distance you take between them, the ratio of force and $m_1m_2/r^2$ will always be equal to $G$.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible because your conclusions 4 and 5 lines from the bottom are Newtons law of gravitation and

$$G=\frac{Fr^2}{M_1M_2}\tag1$$

This could give the same value each time. That is, if you were to measure the force between two masses and the distance between them and work out the value of formula (1), it could give the same number each time, even for different masses and distances - and according to experiment, measurements for planets orbits etc...it seems to do so.

Comment: Yes,I do think we can Find it constant every time experimentally,My intention is just to Find why is it constant mathematically,I think I am lagging a concept of Joint Variation,and getting confused over there

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi It is a constant because that is what is found *experimentally*.  It is not a consequence of mathematics, but the need to match the measurements and predictions of a law of gravitation to the form of law.  That's where $G$ comes from.

Comment: Ohh,Thanks @StephenG,I thought I would get a mathematical proof,But yeh,I know it now that it is just found Experimentally